# how to play a sound alarm or soundeffect that doesn't stop itunes or other music players?

Tags: ios, audio, alarm

I'm working on a sport timer app, that should play alarms after a couple of seconds. Everything works so far but It stops all music players. I used the AVAudioPlayer Class to play the sound. Is there any other way to play the alarms?

thx
Dan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to look into audio session [categories](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioSession_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Audio_Session_Categories).  The default category `AVAudioSessionCategorySoloAmbient` disables other audio, but `AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient` should leave the other audio playing.  If using AVAudioSession, you could try this:

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient error:nil];
```

You should still be able to use AVAudioPlayer.

Comment: Thx, I'll check that out tomorrow. Cheers Dan